# Trying to join the results of two selects in sql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and can not figure out how to join the results from these two selects. Any suggestions?

```
select COUNT(COLORANTCODE) as Colorant_Count from Formula group by COLORANTCODE;

select COLORANTNAME from Colorant;
```

Nothing i have tried has worked.

Formula contains COLORANTCODE which is a FK to Colorant that contains COLORANTCODE AND COLORANTNAME.

I need the resulting table to contain the COLORANTNAME and the count of how many times it appears in Formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT c.colorantname, COALESCE(COUNT(f.colorantcode), 0) count
  FROM colorant c LEFT JOIN Formula f
    ON c.colorantcode = f.colorantcode
 GROUP BY c.colorantcode, c.colorantname
```

Recommended reading:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins)

Comment: actually the answer i needed was SELECT c.COLORANTNAME, COUNT(f.colorantcode)  as Colorant_count FROM Colorant c RIGHT JOIN Formula f ON c.colorantcode = f.colorantcode GROUP BY c.colorantname; but i couldnt have gotten there without your answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COLORANTCODE, Count(*) as Colorant_count  
from Formula  
Group by COLORANTCODE
```